# Replacing legacy system & creating new server code using ServiceStack + custom serialization

Tags: c#, servicestack

We have a legacy server code that we want to abandon and develop new one using ServiceStack. Existing clients are not written in .Net. We don't plan to use .Net on the client side at all.

Data between client and server is being exchanged using XML and JSON - at the moment JSON is only used as a return format for the response (just for some of the services available). XML format was defined when the first version of the server solution was created couple of years ago. We don't want to change it.

How do we use ServiceStack to build new RESTful webservices, that will serialize and deserialize data to a format that was designed in the past (please note, that clients will not be written in C#/.Net). We need to contol both: serialization & deserialization. Is that possible to use DTOs and still have control on how are these objects serialized / deserialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Adding custom logic via Request / Response Filters

See [Request and response filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) to see how to add custom logic before and after your service is called. It's best to add these filters via the [Request / Response FilterAttributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) as it allows you **mark** only the services that need these filters applied.

The problem with the Request Filter is it happens after the deserialization into the request DTO which is too late to add custom de-serialization logic. To get around this you can register a custom Request binder in your AppHost with:

```
base.RegisterRequestBinder<MyRequest>(httpReq => ... requestDto);
```

This gives you access to the IHttpRequest object and lets you add the custom deserialization logic yourself. The other option is to tell ServiceStack to not attempt to deserialize the request itself and instead inject the HttpRequest InputStream so you can deserialize the request yourself:

```
public class Hello : IRequiresRequestStream {
    Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

Both these examples are explained on ServiceStack's [Serialization and De-Serialization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) wiki page.

### Registering your own Custom Media Type

Another option to be able to return strong-typed DTOs but change the output for certain requests can be done by adding a new custom media type as explained in the [Northwind VCard Custom media type example](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/vcard-format.htm), e.g:

```
public static void Register(IAppHost appHost)
{
    appHost.ContentTypeFilters.Register( "text/x-vcard", SerializeToStream,  DeserializeFromStream);
}

...    

public static void SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, object response, Stream stream)
{
    var customerDetailsResponse = response as CustomerDetailsResponse;
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        if (customerDetailsResponse != null)
        {
            WriteCustomer(sw, customerDetailsResponse.Customer);
        }
        var customers = response as CustomersResponse;
        if (customers != null)
        {
            customers.Customers.ForEach(x => WriteCustomer(sw, x));
        }
    }
}
```

This is a good option if you can mount the custom XML responses under a different Content Type, e.g. **application/v-xml** so it doesn't conflict with the existing XML format/endpoint. Using the ContentType above your HTTP Client can call this custom implementation with **?format=v-xml** or using the HTTP Header: **Accept: application/v-xml**.

If you want to override the built-in XML ContentType you still can but I recommend falling back to the original XmlSerializer implementation for the SerializeStream and DeserializeStream methods if it's not one of the legacy formats you have to support.

### By-pass ServiceStack and execute using your own Custom IHttpHandler

Another option is to by-pass ServiceStack completely and instead process the request in your own custom IHttpRequest handler by registering it in ServiceStack's config in your AppHost:

```
 SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { 
    RawHttpHandlers = {
      httpReq => return IsLegacyMatch(httpReq) ? new LegacyXmlHandler() : null 
    }
 });
```

Returning **non-null** (i.e. any handler) by-passes ServiceStack.